# how to set textMode = Multiline for dynamic text box in c#

Tags: c#

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.TextMode = "MulitiLine";
```

is not working

how to set `textMode = Multiline` for dynamic text box in c#

Comment: what is the size of the text box.. have you tried re-sizing the textbox height / width after doing the creation. txt new Textbox();..? txt.textmode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

Answer (score 15):

```
txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
```

hi it will help you to get the solution

Answer (score 4):

```
TextBox tx = new TextBox();
txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Textbox txt = new Textbox();
txt.Multiline = true;
```

It also help you to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
TextBox yourTextBox = new TextBox();
yourTextBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
```